# How to evaluate $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k}{3^{k}}$

Tags: limits

I have to evaluate
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k}{3^{k}}$$

At first, I rewrote it as
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{3^{-k}}{\dfrac{1}{k}}$$
and then, applying L'Hopital rule, I got
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\ln(3)\cdot3^{-k}}{\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}}$$

I feel this is not the way I should follow but I have no ideia how can I evaluate it.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/173061/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1247447/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/372655/42969

Comment: Don't try to oversmart the problem. Apply L'Hopital without rewriting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why didn't you apply L'Hôpital's rule in the original form?

$$
\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{k}{3^k} = \lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{1}{\ln 3 \cdot 3^k} = 0.
$$